Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2) I am getting this error while converting angular 17 to @angular/ssr
I am getting the following error while trying to convert my angular project to @angular/ssr
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node:1:2 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
It is hard for me to find the actual problem as it is not providing me in which component the error exists.
I am using canvas for ng2-charts. I also have chart.js which is dependent for ng2-charts. Also, I am signature_pad packagewhich also uses canvas.
Similarly I am also using angularx-qrcode package.
how would I be able to solve this problem.

Could you provide more details about your Webpack configuration and how you're using the canvas module in your Angular project? Specifically, it would help to know if you're importing canvas in client-side code or server-side only, and if you've made any custom modifications to the Webpack configuration for SSR!

I do not have any webpack.config file. I am using canvas for chart.js, ng2-charts and signature_pad packages.

I would try to delete the folder node_modules/canvas and try to reinstall first (I once had an incomplete js-file downloaded to node_modules because npm did something wrong)
